# How to update vmware tools inside VM when there is an update?

Tags: ubuntu, vmware, vmware-tools

We are making some product that ships with some version of vmware tools and based on Ubuntu 12.04.
In our instances of OVA we don't give users ability to enter inside OS (They enter to CLI).
So our users found that Vmware tools are out of date. 
How I can request ESX/vCenter through vmware tool to update vmware tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VMware tools can't start the update routine.

It gives only 2 Solutions to update the VMware tools...

The vCenter can start an automatic update of the vmware tools, but here can you get a problem with the installation, so the vmware tools are broken and you must install it manual.

Or you install it manual: /path/to/install --default (or with puppet,chef or somthing like that) or you install the open-vm-tools

R\Sven

Comment: nope you can't sorry. You can start the update from the vcenter or the other stuff.